# Sending URL data Curl/Json in Python

Tags: python, curl

I am trying use curl in python with url parameter but it is returning "None", same api with same parameter in php it is working fine.
Here is my python code :

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pycurl, json

apiurl = 'http://servername.com:7705'

data = json.dumps({"node": "test", "type": "get_by_field"})

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, apiurl)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json'])
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
response = c.perform()
c.close()
print response
```

Comment: I suggest you look into `Requests` which has good API for performing HTTP-requests: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
import StringIO
import pycurl, json

fout = StringIO.StringIO()

apiurl = 'http://servername.com:7705'

data = json.dumps({"node": "test", "type": "get_by_field"})

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, fout.write)

c.setopt(pycurl.URL, apiurl)
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: application/json'])
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
c.perform()
c.getinfo(pycurl.RESPONSE_CODE)
fout.getvalue()
```